# MYSQL 8 cannot connect from remote machine

Tags: server, mysql

I've setup a new 20.04.03 LTS Server. I can connect to MySQL locally, but can't connect from workbench on remote machine.

I've created my user username@% and granted all permissions.

I went an edited  `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
and added `bind_address    = 0.0.0.0` The line was not already in there.

I've logged into mysql on the localhost and checked

```
mysql> show variables like "%bind%";
+---------------------+---------+
| Variable_name       | Value   |
+---------------------+---------+
| bind_address        | 0.0.0.0 |
| mysqlx_bind_address | *       |
+---------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then resarted the mysql service and when that did not fix it I rebooted the machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you confirmed that UFW isn’t blocking connections?

Comment: ufw is inactive